# How to bind data in a JavaFX Cell

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Since [Cells](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html) are virtualized in JavaFX im not sure where to bind the data.

According to the docs the cells can be recycled (re-used) anytime.

Currently my code looks like this **(1)**:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Object value, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(value, empty);
    if (empty || value == null) {
        setGraphic(null);
        return;
    }

    if (!isBound) {
        myLabel.textProperty().bind(value.myProperty());
        isBound = true;
    }
    //no unbinding?
}
```

But i don't know when to unbind the property.

So i thought it's maybe better to do this **in constructor (2)**:

```
itemProperty().addListener((list, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            if(newValue != null) {
                myLabel.textProperty().bind(newValue.myProperty());
            }
            if(oldValue != null) {
                myLabel.textProperty.unbind();
            }   
});
```

But i noticed that the ChangeListener of itemProperty() is called more often then really necessary so it will consume more performance.
If i'm right i'll have wrong binded items sometime with solution (1). 
How would you handle this?

**Edit - Idea: (3)**

```
    private Object boundObj;

    @Override
        protected void updateItem(Object value, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(value, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
                return;
            }

            if (boundObj != null && value != boundObj) {
                myLabel.textProperty().unbind();
                boundObj = null;
            }
            else {
                myLabel.textProperty().bind(value.topicProperty());
                boundObj = value;
            }

            setGraphic(gridPane);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution 2 (updating the binding with a listener) is in general the correct way to do this. The item can change quite often (particularly when the user scrolls), and you need to change the binding when this happens.

If you are concerned about performance, which I don't think you need to be, the `ChangeListener` is **only** invoked if the item actually changes. The `updateItem(...)` method is invoked any time the item changes, but may be invoked more frequently. So observing the `itemProperty` is at worst no less efficient than the `updateItem(...)` approach.

At any rate, you are unlikely to see performance issues here. All you do is update the text of a label (and you need to do that when the item changes however you approach it), then the binding will register a listener, which is a lightweight operation.

In this particular example, you can simplify it by just calling `unbind()` unconditionally. If the property is not bound, this [has no effect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html#unbind--). So you can do:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Object value, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(value, empty);

    myLabel.textProperty().unbind();

    if (empty || value == null) {
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        setGraphic(myLabel);
        myLabel.textProperty().bind(value.myProperty());
    }
}
```

This doesn't generalize to other scenarios though, for example if, instead of binding a label, you were bidirectionally binding the `textProperty` of a `TextField`.

You can just about do this in general in the `updateItem(...)` method, by noticing that `getItem()` will return the old item if you call it before calling `super.updateItem(...)`:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Object value, boolean empty) {

    Object oldItem = getItem();
    if (oldItem != null) {
        myLabel.textProperty().unbind();
    }

    super.updateItem(value, empty);

    if (empty || value == null) {
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        setGraphic(myLabel);
        myLabel.textProperty().bind(value.myProperty());
    }
}
```

I like this solution less, as it relies a bit on the library implementation (`getItem()` returning the old item in this context is not documented behavior). Additionally it's potentially less efficient, as the change listener is *only* invoked when the item changes; no such guarantees are made for the `updateItem(...)` method.

Notice if you use the recommended approach and observe the `itemProperty` you can often get away without subclassing the cell class at all:

```
myListView.setCellFactory(listView -> {
    ListCell<SomeType> cell = new ListCell<>(); // default implementation
    Label myLabel = new Label();
    cell.itemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (oldValue != null) {
            myLabel.textProperty().unbind();
        }
        if (newValue == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            myLabel.bind(newValue.myProperty());
            setGraphic(myLabel);
        }
    });
    return cell ;
});
```

(This fits nicely with my own programming style, where I try to avoid unnecessary inheritance. Obviously that is just a matter of personal taste.)

Your third option fails if the cell changes from non-empty (i.e. it had a non-null item, to which the label's text was bound) to empty, because you fail to unbind in that case. You might be able to re-jig the logic to account for that, but it seems you'd just be making it unduly complex. Using the change listener is the way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply James. I've added a third solution, maybe you'll have look a it? :)

Comment: I don't think it works as it stands. See updated answer. You might be able to make it work that way but you'd be making it too complex; use the change listener.

Comment: It work's if you add a field "Object boundObj". Or let's say it's compiling and no errors come up on startup. Anyway - your answer is pretty good and you pointed the advantages out. That convinces me.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered a similar problem and the answer here gave me some guidance, however I think the solution should be different.

From [ListView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html) javadoc:

> The elements of the ListView are contained within the items ObservableList. This ObservableList is automatically observed by the ListView, such that any changes that occur inside the ObservableList will be automatically shown in the ListView itself.

So you don't need to bind the cell elements to the underlying items, JavaFX does that for you. Something like this will do:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(MyData value, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(value, empty);
    if (value == null || empty) {
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        setGraphic(myGraphic);
        myLabel.textProperty().set(value.getTextProperty().get());
    }
}
```

This way you have fixed the binding that propagates from model to graphic, somewhat. You still need to make sure that the list is notified if an essential property from your MyItem gets changed. You use an observable list with an [extractor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-) for that.

If you want some changes that you make in the view to be reflected in the model, you can just set up your choice of listener. You can do this in the constructor or cell factory callable.

```
MyCell extends ListCell<MyData> {
    TextField myText = new TextField();
    public MyCell(){
        myText.textProperty().addListener((observable,oldValue,newValue) -> {
            if (newValue != null) getItem().setName(newValue);
        });
    }
}
```

This way you can express your business logic next to your domain and have the cells only handle the mapping between model and view and mapping between user action and program logic.

I've tried to do bindings as James_D recommended but with bidirectional bindings. The results were pretty bad. Cells getting item properties changed to null randomly when changes were being made to the ObservableList. Simple bindings work, but in my opinion are superfluous. You already register a listener, why bind to data to which you are already listening to? Just make the changes in the listener callback.